# Android Studio - add .jar library

Tags: android, hibernate, gradle, android-studio, build.gradle

This seems an old answered question, but I'm still having some issues.
I created a Web Server that shares some classes as .jar. This is an example of a shared POJO class

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", uniqueConstraints =
{ @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email"),
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "nick") })
public class User implements java.io.Serializable, RecognizedServerEntities
{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
  private Integer userId;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "threadAuthor",
      orphanRemoval = false)
  @Cascade({ CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE })
  private Set<Thread> userThreads = new HashSet<Thread>(0);
}
```

Now, I'm trying to create an android app that simply use these shared classes: the app doesn't need to know anything about hibernate or javax.persistence (at least, is what I think).
However, when I create a new project in `Android Studio`, it seems to require some additional libraries. Indeed, the gradle build process generates a lot of warnings like

```
warning: unknown enum constant CascadeType.REMOVE
  reason: class file for org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType not found
warning: unknown enum constant FetchType.EAGER
  reason: class file for javax.persistence.FetchType not found
```

and at runtime the app crashes with this log message

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/annotations/Cascade
```

So, do I have to import these `.jar`s as library and add a `compile files()` to `build.gradle`?
I've yet developed another client-side application using Java (Swing) and there is no need to import those libraries: the shared.jar was enough. Why do Android require them?

Comment: You may try to add, and see what happened.

Comment: @bjiang  know, but there are a lot of libraries to add and it seems 
an unnecessary waste of space. However, I just tried to add javax.persistence and hibernate-core to the list of jars: while the build process runs without warnings, runtime errors occurs anyway. Is it strictly necessary to add these jars?

Answer (score 1):

`CascadeType` and `FetchType` are part of Java EE.
Try use [findjar](http://www.findjar.com/class/javax/persistence/CascadeType.html) to download jar(s) which contains these classes.

Even if you will add downloaded jars to classpath, `RuntimeException`s still migt happen because these libs can use part of Java that isn't part of Android Java.

Just try and give us a feedback :)

Comment: Thanks for your time.
Can you take a look at the comment below the original question? Is it strictly necessary to add these jars?

Comment: @tigerjack89 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/annotations/Cascade - I'd try add jars :)

Comment: Yet tried: I haven't compile warnings anymore, but the app still crashes with runtime errors.

Comment: @tigerjack89 runtime still says that not found CascadeType?

Comment: WTF restarted Android Studio and now it works without errors :S

Comment: Well, your tips and the ones from @CommonsWare helped me in many ways and both deserve an up vote, but it's difficult to say that they are the final answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Now, I'm trying to create an android app that simply use these shared classes: the app doesn't need to know anything about hibernate or javax.persistence (at least, is what I think).

Apparently, it does. Some of those annotations may be runtime annotations, in which case, you would need the JARs. Some of those that are compile-time annotations may expand into references to things in those JARs, and that is my interpretation of your error messages.

> So, do I have to import these .jars as library and add a compile files() to build.gradle?

You are certainly welcome to try using Hibernate on Android, whether through JARs or artifacts up at someplace like Maven Central. Whether there is a port of Hibernate that works on Android, I cannot say. Last I checked, Hibernate was designed for server-side use with direct access to a database, whereas Android apps are designed for client-side use without direct access to a database (e.g., using a Web service).

Comment: Well, is what I've done so far. I've implemented the server-side project using POJO classes and now I'd like to use an Android app only to access this server. However, I've shared some of those POJOs so, for example, I can easily create a new User from the Client and send it to the Server, which in turns save it to the database.
Also, I've yet developed another client-side application using Java (Swing) and there is no need to import those libraries: the shared.jar was enough.
However, I tried to include the jars in the Android project, but the runtime errors are still there.

Comment: @tigerjack89: Well, in terms of `javax.persistence`, that simply isn't on Android and is unlikely to be something that you can add, as Android's build tools usually reject classes in an app (or library) that are in the `java` or `javax` namespaces. However, those are not runtime errors; they are warnings. The Dalvik (and presumably ART) runtimes will post warnings about missing stuff. If you really need the stuff, you will crash with a `VerifyError` at the point of executing the code.

Comment: The warnings aren't the real problem. Problem is that at runtime, even after adding those libraries, the app crashes and the logcat says `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/annotations/Cascade` (however, no build errors)

Comment: @tigerjack89: And so you need a JAR that contains that class in your APK at runtime. The fact that on a largely unrelated runtime (whatever Java SE version you used for your Swing client) happens to not need this class is not especially relevant. "Why do Android require them?" -- because you are using them. Depending on the specific trigger behind the error, you may have a stack trace that shows what specific part of your code is going through a path that happens to require this class. In this case, it would appear to be a runtime annotation.

Comment: I tried to add many jars; indeed, compile time warnings are gone, but it still has runtime errors: aren't the two things related? I mean, the fact that I don't have compile warnings anymore doesn't imply that I shouldn't have runtime errors?

Comment: @tigerjack89: "I tried to add many jars" -- if you are still getting the runtime errors, there would appear to be some issue in how you added the JARs. That's unusual with Android Studio; I am more used to that sort of problem in Eclipse. What JARs did you add, and how did you add them? Also, if there is a full stack trace associated with your `NoClassDefFoundError`, could you post it?

Comment: Just restarted Android Studio and now it works great. So, is this the final solution?

Comment: @tigerjack89: Well, I certainly can't explain why restarting the IDE would have an impact on your app running in your device/emulator. I mean, stranger things have happened, but I can't say "oh, yes, by restarting the IDE you caused X to happen, which impacted Y, etc.".